# How can I activate subtitles by default in the Dailymotion embedded player for any language

Tags: dailymotion-api

Dailymotion embed URLs can activate subtitles by default:

https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7n59nb?subtitles-default=en

But the embed player needs to know the language for that.

It would be nice to be able to activate subtitles regardless of language for the
video software I am using, as I don't want to store the language for every video.

Is there a way to activate just any subtitle eg:

https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7n59nb?subtitles-default=any (or first)

Or to give the player a list of possible subtitles:

https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x7n59nb?subtitles-default=de,en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to directly activate subtitles with a random value.

- With an API call you can retrieve the list of available subtitles for a specific video by using the endpoint: `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{id_of_video}/subtitles` [Documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#video-subtitles-connection)
- If you are in a browser, you can maybe use the `navigator.language` to set the value of the subtitles.
- With the dailymotion-sdk-js ([Documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks/#sdk-javascript)), you can use the events to set your subtitle randomly:

```
var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
        video: "x7n59nb"
    });

    player.addEventListener('playback_ready', function (e)
        { 
            if(e.target.subtitles.length > 0){
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(e.target.subtitles.length));
                playlists.setSubtitle(e.target.subtitles[random])
            }
        });
```

Comment: As my software has no control over the client, the client sdk is not an option.


But thanks you for your response. 

Without a wildcard language "*" I have to store available languages for every video and store this to produce embed tags with subtitles, for the frontend system.